# What is a organizational device considered to be?

Tags: user-account, mobile-device-management

Would this be a device that is a organizational device because you get it from work? Or because of who makes the device? What is a organizational device. How can I find out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Apple software or hardware

Answer (score 1):

In the context of MDM ([Mobile Device Management](https://www.apple.com/business/it/)), an "organizational device" is a device (mobile phone, laptop, tablet, etc.) that is owned and controlled by the organization (usually a company, school, etc.) that has legal ownership of it.

The alternative is BYOD ([Bring Your Own Device](https://www.techradar.com/news/computing/what-is-byod-and-why-is-it-important-1175088)) where the end user brings their personal device to access the organization's IT resources (i.e. email, calendar, shared files, etc.)